# Acessar EJB Remoto dentro de outro EJB

Tags: java, jboss, ejb

Boa tarde a todos.

Estou em um projeto que preciso fazer um lookup de um EJB remoto dentro de outro EJB em um container diferente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema esta quando tento fazer o lookup o InitialContext esta dando o seguinte erro.

```
11:12:15,377 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1) java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to create remoting connection [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to setup EJB remote context]

11:12:15,377 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at br.com.seta.portal.service.bonita.integration.JndiContext.getContext(JndiContext.java:37)

11:12:15,378 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at br.com.seta.portal.service.bonita.integration.BonitaIntegration.getIntegracaoBonitaConsultar(BonitaIntegration.java:38)

11:12:15,378 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at br.com.seta.portal.service.bonita.BonitaServiceImpl.consultarGrupos(BonitaServiceImpl.java:75)

11:12:15,378 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

11:12:15,378 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

11:12:15,378 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

11:12:15,378 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)

11:12:15,378 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)

11:12:15,379 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

11:12:15,379 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)

11:12:15,379 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)

11:12:15,379 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

11:12:15,379 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:374)

11:12:15,379 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:86)

11:12:15,379 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:97)

11:12:15,380 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)

11:12:15,380 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

11:12:15,380 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)

11:12:15,380 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)

11:12:15,380 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

11:12:15,380 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)

11:12:15,380 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

11:12:15,380 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)

11:12:15,381 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

11:12:15,381 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:73)

11:12:15,382 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

11:12:15,382 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)

11:12:15,382 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

11:12:15,383 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)

11:12:15,383 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53)

11:12:15,384 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

11:12:15,384 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)

11:12:15,385 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

11:12:15,385 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:280)

11:12:15,385 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:345)

11:12:15,385 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:243)

11:12:15,387 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

11:12:15,387 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)

11:12:15,387 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

11:12:15,387 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43)

11:12:15,388 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

11:12:15,388 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)

11:12:15,388 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

11:12:15,388 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59)

11:12:15,389 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

11:12:15,389 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)

11:12:15,389 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

11:12:15,389 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55)

11:12:15,389 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

11:12:15,389 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45)

11:12:15,389 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

11:12:15,389 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)

11:12:15,389 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:185)

11:12:15,390 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)

11:12:15,390 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

11:12:15,390 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)

11:12:15,390 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73)

11:12:15,390 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at br.com.seta.portal.service.bonita.BonitaService$$$view37.consultarGrupos(Unknown Source)

11:12:15,390 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

11:12:15,390 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

11:12:15,390 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

11:12:15,390 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)

11:12:15,390 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:267)

11:12:15,390 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)

11:12:15,390 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)

11:12:15,391 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:263)

11:12:15,391 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:115)

11:12:15,391 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)

11:12:15,391 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:105)

11:12:15,391 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at br.com.seta.portal.service.bonita.BonitaService$-1057754167$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.consultarGrupos(BonitaService$-1057754167$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.java)

11:12:15,391 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at br.com.seta.portal.webservice.ConsultaPermissaoWSImpl_V2.validarUsuario(ConsultaPermissaoWSImpl_V2.java:39)

11:12:15,391 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

11:12:15,391 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

11:12:15,392 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

11:12:15,392 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)

11:12:15,392 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)

11:12:15,393 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

11:12:15,393 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)

11:12:15,394 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)

11:12:15,394 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

11:12:15,394 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)

11:12:15,394 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)

11:12:15,394 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

11:12:15,394 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)

11:12:15,395 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

11:12:15,395 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)

11:12:15,395 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53)

11:12:15,395 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

11:12:15,395 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.as.webservices.deployers.WSComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.processInvocation(WSComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.java:49)

11:12:15,395 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

11:12:15,396 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)

11:12:15,396 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:185)

11:12:15,397 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.as.webservices.invocation.AbstractInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:129)

11:12:15,397 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker.performInvocation(JBossWSInvoker.java:177)

11:12:15,397 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:104)

11:12:15,397 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:237)

11:12:15,398 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:69)

11:12:15,398 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker.invoke(JBossWSInvoker.java:146)

11:12:15,398 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)

11:12:15,398 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)

11:12:15,398 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)

11:12:15,398 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)

11:12:15,398 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:107)

11:12:15,399 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)

11:12:15,399 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)

11:12:15,399 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:249)

11:12:15,399 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:97)

11:12:15,399 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.transport.ServletHelper.callRequestHandler(ServletHelper.java:131)

11:12:15,399 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.invoke(CXFServletExt.java:88)

11:12:15,399 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:286)

11:12:15,399 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:206)

11:12:15,399 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)

11:12:15,399 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.service(CXFServletExt.java:136)

11:12:15,400 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.wsf.spi.deployment.WSFServlet.service(WSFServlet.java:140)

11:12:15,400 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)

11:12:15,400 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)

11:12:15,400 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)

11:12:15,400 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:267)

11:12:15,400 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:201)

11:12:15,400 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:282)

11:12:15,400 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)

11:12:15,400 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)

11:12:15,400 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231)

11:12:15,400 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)

11:12:15,400 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)

11:12:15,400 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)

11:12:15,401 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)

11:12:15,401 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:150)

11:12:15,401 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)

11:12:15,401 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)

11:12:15,401 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)

11:12:15,401 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:854)

11:12:15,401 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653)

11:12:15,401 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926)

11:12:15,401 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

11:12:15,402 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1) Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to create remoting connection [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to setup EJB remote context]

11:12:15,402 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.ClientUtil.namingException(ClientUtil.java:51)

11:12:15,402 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(InitialContextFactory.java:151)

11:12:15,402 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:122)

11:12:15,402 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:107)

11:12:15,402 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(InitialLdapContext.java:154)

11:12:15,402 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:98)

11:12:15,402 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(InitialContextFactory.java:44)

11:12:15,402 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)

11:12:15,402 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)

11:12:15,402 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)

11:12:15,403 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)

11:12:15,403 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at br.com.seta.portal.service.bonita.integration.JndiContext.getContext(JndiContext.java:35)

11:12:15,403 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    ... 134 more

11:12:15,403 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to setup EJB remote context

11:12:15,403 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.setupEjbContext(InitialContextFactory.java:468)

11:12:15,403 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(InitialContextFactory.java:145)

11:12:15,403 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    ... 144 more

11:12:15,404 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1) Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

11:12:15,404 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

11:12:15,404 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

11:12:15,404 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

11:12:15,404 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)

11:12:15,404 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.setupEjbContext(InitialContextFactory.java:448)

11:12:15,404 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    ... 145 more

11:12:15,404 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1) Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: EJBCLIENT000021: EJB client context selector may not be changed

11:12:15,404 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.setSelector(EJBClientContext.java:218)

11:12:15,405 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.ejb.RemoteNamingEjbClientContextSelector.setupSelector(RemoteNamingEjbClientContextSelector.java:28)

11:12:15,405 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-1)    ... 150 more
```

Só que esse erro somente acontece quando tento criar o lookup dentro do EJB, se faço um teste criando o lookup por um static void main por exemplo ele funciona perfeitamente.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

O codigo segue abaixo.

Crio o JndiContext

```
public class JndiContext {

    private String  hostNameEjb; 
    private Integer portNameEjb;

    public JndiContext() {
            hostNameEjb  = "192.168.2.198";
            portNameEjb  = 4447;
     }


    public Context getContext( )  {
        try {
            Hashtable<String, Object> jndiProperties = new Hashtable();
            jndiProperties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
            jndiProperties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"remote://"+hostNameEjb+":"+portNameEjb);
            jndiProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "admin");
            jndiProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "admin123.");
            jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
            jndiProperties.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context",true);
            jndiProperties.put("remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED",false);
            jndiProperties.put("remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS",false);
            jndiProperties.put("remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOPLAINTEXT",false);
//          jndiProperties.put("remote.cluster.ejb.clusternode.selector","org.jboss.ejb.client.RandomClusterNodeSelector");
//          jndiProperties.put("remote.clusters","ejb");
            jndiProperties.put("org.jboss.ejb.client.scoped.context",true);
            return new InitialContext(jndiProperties);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Serviço

```
@Override
private IntegracaoBonitaCadastrar getIntegracaoBonitaCadastrar() { 
        IntegracaoBonitaCadastrar remote = null;
        try {
            Context ctx = new JndiContext().getContext();
            remote = (IntegracaoBonitaCadastrar) this.ctx.lookup(LOOCKUP_CADASTRO);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return remote;
    }
```

Estou utilizando JBoss EAP 6.3 em ambos os servers.

Comment: Você poderia postar só os erros relevantes?

Comment: Então esse é log de erro que aparece quando da o erro.